# Slow multi layed select in SQL query needs to be improved

Tags: mysql, symfony-1.4

I have a single query on my website (the only one not in DQL) which is slowing down one of the websites I am working on. Basically the table is a log of what users have done over the website so that I can show this on a live feed. However it also needs to combine these lines so that if a user uploads multiple images, instead of having a row for each, it produces 1 row with all of the images listed in it.

At the moment this is done via a query and then an iterator. The query gets the ID of the highest row of that type and the number of matching rows. The code will then use this to decide which type of data row to process it by which will then iterator over the number of rows it's told.

**Table:**

```
UserLog:
  actAs:
    Timestampable:
    DmBlameable:
  columns:
    record_model:       { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    record_id:          { type: integer, notnull: true }
    record_created_by:  { type: integer }
    body:               { type: string(255) }
    is_active:          { type: boolean, notnull: true, default: true } 
    privacy:            { type: integer, default: 10 }
  relations:
    RecordCreatedBy:
      class:          DmUser
      local:          record_created_by
      foreignAlias:   UserLogs
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS id, count(*) AS numCondensed
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             (SELECT count(*) FROM user_log u2 
              WHERE u2.id <= t.id 
              AND ( u2.record_model <> t.record_model 
              OR u2.created_by <> t.created_by
              OR u2.body <> t.body) ) AS grp
      FROM user_log t ) t 
WHERE privacy <= 10 GROUP BY created_by, record_model, body, grp 
ORDER BY `id`  DESC
```

**Example output**

```
id  numCondensed
1806    1
1805    1
1804    11
1793    1
1792    1
1791    1
1790    1
1789    10
1779    1
1778    1
```

On a table with 1700 rows (595 rows from query) this is taking 1.2 seconds to run. And with 6859 rows (3300 rows from query) it takes about 23 seconds. There are possible options in WHERE clause as well, but they don't seam to effect the timing. There are indexes in place on all rows that are used in the SELECTS and GROUP BY's.

I have no objections to making tables/views or rewriting it completely as long as the resulting view to the user is the same. But I couldn't work out the correct method to do any of these and save a sufficient amount of time.

The code is written in Symfony 1.4 for legacy reasons with Doctrine and MYSQL 5.1 on local (1.2 seconds) and 5.5 on live (23 seconds).

**EDIT - Query Explain:**

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY     <derived2>  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1725    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
2   DERIVED     t   ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1699    
3   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  u2  ALL     PRIMARY     NULL    NULL    NULL    1699    Using where
```

Comment: I formatted your query, see if you agree.

Comment: First of all, I think you must have the same version of MySQL on your local than on live. Next, you should run an EXPLAIN of your query, maybe you are missing some index that can speed up your query. And finally, why don't you _condense_ lines on insert? I mean, when a user uploads a photo, you create a line. When it uploads a new one, you should detect that the previous line was also an upload and then merge them and add a counter or something so you know this line refer to more than one action.

Comment: I've added the explain to the post.

I can't use the same version of MYSQL on both. My development server can't use 5.5 due to my OS, and the live server needs 5.4 to support emoji.

As for the condensing, the lines all have a privacy value, which is the privacy value of the post it references. This is done to save 100 extra joins. So when a privacy change is done on the object it changes the privacy on the line as well. This effects the counts as it removes lines from public view.